# I don't know how to strip the end of this line

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, strip

I have to enter two numbers in a function, and it outputs a string of odd numbers between the two numbers that you enter. Everything seems to be working fine, but I can't figure out how to strip the end correctly.

```
# getOdds.py
# A function that receives two integers and returns a string of consecutive even numbers between the two integers.

# Define the getOdds() functions
def getOdds(p, q):
    """ returns a string of odd numbers between integers p & q """

    # Define odd number string
    x = p
    while x <= q:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x += 1

     # Calculate & print string
        else:
            print(x, end = ", ")
            str(x).strip(", ")
            x += 2
```

I just want the last number to not have a ", " at the end of it (eg. 1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 2, 3, ).

Why won't strip() work in this case? And what should I do instead?

Comment: once you have `print`ed it out you can't strip away the output, you will need a way to **not** do `end=", "` for the last one in order to not have the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to stop the `,` from showing up at the last element is to prevent `end=", "` from happening on the last print, there are a few ways of going about this, but the simplest in my mind is to get a sequence of all the things you want to print and do it in one go, the print function is great at this:

```
>>> print(*range(5), sep=", ")
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

You can make your own function behave this way by putting it into a helper generator function, instead of `print(x,end=", ")` you would simply `yield x`:

```
def getOdds_gen_helper(p, q):
    """ generates odd numbers between integers p & q """

    # Define odd number string
    x = p
    while x <= q:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x += 1

     # Calculate & print string
        else:
            yield x #!!! yield the values
            str(x).strip(", ")
            x += 2
```

Then your actual `getOdds` function would simply call the helper like the above print statement:

```
def getOdds(p,q):  
    """ prints all of the odd numbers between integers p & q """

    print(*getOdds_gen_helper(p,q), sep=", ")
```

Note that your original docstring actually says "returns .." but it in fact returns nothing, if you wanted to return this string instead of printing it that would be equally easy with the generator and the `str.join` method:

```
def getOdds(p,q):  
    """ returns a string of odd numbers between integers p & q """
    return ", ".join(str(p) for p in getOdds_gen_helper(p, q))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `str.strip` does not operate in-place, and you aren't doing anything with the new, returned value. Second, `str.strip` does not work on content you have already printed to the console. Instead, check whether the loop is at its last iteration, and don't print the comma at that point.

```
else:
    print(x, end = "")
    x += 2
    if x <= q: #if the while loop is still going to continue
        print(', ',end="")
    else: #end of the function, finish the line
        print()
```

Or you could use a single `print()` call and the `range()` function:

```
def getOdds(p, q):
    print(*range(p if p%2 else p+1, q+1, 2), sep=', ')
```

Result:

```
>>> getOdds(3, 10)
3, 5, 7, 9
>>> getOdds(3, 11)
3, 5, 7, 9, 11
```

Note that, as @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen says in the comments below, `p if p%2 else p+1` can be replaced with `p|1`, which uses a bitwise OR operation to produce the same result.

Comment: however this falls apart when passing an even number as the first argument.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - Thanks, fixed.

Comment: while few people understand how it works, I find `p|1` to be a really simple way of saying "add one if it is even"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - This is true; edited. However, I prefer the ternary operator over bitwise operations, generally.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print numbers while in the loop, accumulate and return them. I.e.

```
def odds(q, p):
   q += (2 if q % 2 else 1)
   return range(q, p, 2)

my_odds = (str(n) for n in odds(1, 9))
print(", ".join(my_odds))
```

Comment: This consistently only produces even numbers, I think you have the `1` and `0` reversed my friend.

Comment: Could just be `q += not q%2` then.

Comment: Thanks, it's very possible, but that's not the point. The actual question was about displaying results, should be easy to adjust the function as needed.

Comment: It should still display corrects results, though - why refuse to fix it?